# Text Change with JavaScript isn't retained in popover after exiting

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a popover that activates over each link to a user containing functionality to Follow/Unfollow.

- Hovering on the link displays the popover
- The popover displays: "Follow"
- Clicking Follow sends an Ajax request
- Ajax responds successfully and changes the text to Unfollow
- Exciting the popover and then hovering over the same link it reverts back to Follow.

...

```
$('body').popover({ selector: '[data-popover]', trigger: 'click hover', placement: 'right', delay: {show: 50, hide: 400}});


$(document).on('click', '.follow-user .follow, .follow-user .unfollow', function(){
    var el = $(this);

    var actionType = el.hasClass('unfollow') ? 'unfollow' : 'follow';

    var data = {
        actionType: actionType,
        userId: el.attr("data-uid")
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{{path('ajax_follow_user')}}',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function(){
            alert('Error. please try again later!');
            el.removeClass('following');
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            el.addClass('following');
        },
        success: function(r){
            alert("success");
            if(r.error != '') {
                alert(r.error);
                return false;
            }
            alert(actionType);
            if (actionType == 'follow')
            {
                el.text("Unfollow");
                el.stop().removeClass('follow').addClass('unfollow');
            }
            else if (actionType == 'unfollow')
            {
                el.text("Follow");
                el.stop().removeClass('unfollow').addClass('follow');
            }

            el.removeClass('following').text(r.label);
        }
    });
});
```

.

```
<a href="#"
       data-popover="true"
       data-html="true"
       data-content='
<img src="{{ asset(user.avatar) }}" alt="{{ user.username }}"
     width="80" height="80" style="float:left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0"/> 
<strong>{{ user.username }}</strong> <br />
<span class="follow-user">
    {% if user in loggedInUser.followingUsersOnly %}
        <a class="unfollow" data-uid="{{ user.id }}">Unfollow</a>
    {% else %}
        <a class="follow" data-uid="{{ user.id }}">Follow</a>
    {% endif %}
</span> 
<div style="clear:both"></div> <br />'>
        {{ user.username }}
    </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be wrong on this, but you may have to destroy the popover and re-create it with the content within the success callback.

I've found the popover is only within the DOM when it it shown, and removed when it isn't.  (Which is preventing you from changing the text as you are).

```
$('body').popover('destroy');
var options = {
    html: true,
    selector: '[data-popover]',
    trigger: 'click hover',
    placement: 'right',
    delay: {show: 50, hide: 400},
    content: '<img src="{{ asset(user.avatar) }}" alt="{{ user.username }}"
        width="80" height="80" style="float:left; margin: 0 10px 10px 0"/> 
        <strong>{{ user.username }}</strong> <br />
        <span class="follow-user">
        {% if user in loggedInUser.followingUsersOnly %}
            <a class="unfollow" data-uid="{{ user.id }}">Unfollow</a>
        {% else %}
            <a class="follow" data-uid="{{ user.id }}">Follow</a>
        {% endif %}
        </span> 
        <div style="clear:both"></div> <br />'
};
$('body').popover(options);
//This is not needed, but it shows the popover
$('body').popover("show");
```

I'm not too sure how the popovers work with angularjs/django so interpolation values might get messed up.